# Alexa Skill Video Api Python

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to setup a video skill for alexa, however I don't know how to play a video using the video api.

I've tried searching "alexa skill python video api" but I just get links to alexa skills kit. I've also tried reading the python sdk documentation but that didn't help. It seems like you have to send a directive or something.

Currently I have

```
class PlayHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return is_intent_name("PlayVidIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        speech_text = "Playing video"
        # Get the video url
        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).set_card(SimpleCard("Video started", speech_text)).set_should_end_session(True)
        return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

Note: When I checked the documentation it said you had to have the video url so just assume the video url is in a variable called video_url.
More details:
Custom Skill(No video app template or Interaction model template for video skill)
Python 3.4(For server) and Python 3.5(For testing)

Comment: Ordering people who might be helping you  to do is ASAP is not usually turning out the way you hope. It helps though if you have a clear question that shows that you have tried to solve the problem yourself, and describes what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import modules from [ask_sdk_model.interfaces.videoapp](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/ask_sdk_model.interfaces.videoapp.html)

From there you will create a `LaunchDirective` and create `VideoItem` object to be passed as the `video_item` argument. The `VideoItem` object has 2 arguments(that are optional according to the SDK), `source` which is a string of the URL and a `metadata` argument which is created with `Metadata(title="Title", subtitle="Subtitle")`. Finally use `response_builder.add_directive` to add the directive to the response.